# kinetic formula question

Tags: physics

The formula is $K = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$.

Which part is the square supposed to influence? Does it affect just $v$, $mv$ or $\frac{1}{2}mv$?

The problem is $\frac{1}{2} (1.2\cdot 10^5 [kg]) \cdot 40.8^2 \left[\frac{m}{s}\right]$. How would this resolve?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for physics.SE. Also: The question does not exhibit any attempt at a solution! Here I leave a hint: Try to check whether the units of the quantities on both sides of the equality are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has
$$
\frac 12 mv^2=\frac 12 m\cdot v\cdot v\ne\frac 12 (mv)^2=\frac 12 mv \cdot mv=\frac 12 m^2 \cdot v^2
$$ giving here
$$
K=\frac 12 \cdot 1.2 \cdot 10^5 \cdot (40.8)^2=\cdots,
$$ hope you can finish it.

Comment: But if I do the calculations, it's 1997.5 X 10^5, yet the book says 2.0 X 10^8. It doesn't make any sense. Math is too inconsistent.

Comment: Rounding until the third significant digit it's $1.00·10^8$